# how to keep browser open (using existing session) for each scenario in capybara selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am new to write integration tests in rails. Let's say i have below scenarios,

1. Admin logs in.
2. Creates a new user.
3. Assign new role to user.

So currently for every scenario , it opens a new browser window (or may be resetting the session).
As for login we are using 3rd party oauth it takes huge amount of time for login.

So i do not want to login for each scenario. Once after login it should execute scenarios one by one without asking for login again and again. But i am not sure how to achieve the same using rspec and selenium.

Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: You can move other test cases into functions, then in one test case after login just call remaining functions one by one if you don't care about independence of test cases.

Answer (score 3):

`Capybara.current_session.instance_variable_set(:@touched, false)`

Executing the above after each scenario maintains the session.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium shouldn't be opening a new browser window for each scenario (unless you're specifically closing the tab in an after block), but it should reset it to `about:blank`.  As for the rest of your request, it would be completely bypassing the intention of feature/integration tests where each test should be completely isolated from the other tests. What you should be doing, if you don't want to manually login for each test, is using the test mode of whatever auth library you're using to allow you to shortcut the login.

For instance, if using OmniAuth - see https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Comment: I agree, it does not closes the browser but resets the session. But for my case i do not want that, is there any way to prevent it

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy Not easily - it specifically doesn't do what you want because it would allow one test to affect others.

Comment: I am using some custom java based oauth library, do not have such test mode.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy Well I assume you're using a ruby oauth library to communicate with the java based one, implement a test mode for it, it's better than attempting to introduce cross scenario coupling.